# Concatenate duplicates with delimiter

Tags: sql-server

There is several examples that concatenate string dealing with one single table. In my case I have two tables to take into account.

Table A
requestid int PK

Table B
requestid int
documentname varchar(50)

Table A requestid is of course unique, where table B requestid may have multiple lines. Table B can contain multiple relationship with the same requestid from table A. Also some of the Table A requestid might not have any associated records in table B.

I need to extract and join the two tables. Table A contains ~300k lines and table B contains ~140k lines. See the data below to illustrate what I need to achieve.

Table A sample

```
requestid FieldA FieldB FieldC  
1         33     44     22  
2         15     23     73  
3         26     73     34
```

Table B sample

```
requestid documentname  
1          firstdoc.doc  
1          seconddoc.doc  
1          thirddoc.doc  
3          onedoc.doc  
3          lastdoc.doc
```

Expected result:

```
requestid FieldA FieldB FieldC documentname
 1         33     44     22     firstdoc.doc, seconddoc.doc, thirddoc.doc
 2         15     23     73     NULL
 3         26     73     24     onedoc.doc, lastdoc.doc
```

In my solution it is very important that requestid with no document associated to it are still in the result.

Hope my question is clear, thank you in advance.

Comment: All you need is to concatenate the strings in Table B, and then JOIN Table A to the result.   Did you try something and get an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be easily done with a `stuff`
See the example below

```
declare @tableA table (requestid int, fieldA int, fieldB int, fieldC int)
declare @tableB table (requestid int, documentname varchar(50))

insert into @tableA values (1, 33, 44, 22), (2, 15, 23, 73), (3, 26, 73, 34)
insert into @tableB values (1, 'firstdoc.doc'), (1, 'seconddoc.doc'), (1, 'thirddoc.doc'), (3, 'onedoc.doc'), (3, 'lastdoc.doc')

select a.requestid, a.fieldA, a.fieldB, a.fieldC,
       stuff(( ( select ',' + b.documentname
                 from   @tableB b
                 where  b.requestid = a.requestid
                 order by 1
                 For XML PATH (''))
              ), 1, 1, '') as docname
from   @tableA a
```

the result is

```
requestid   fieldA  fieldB  fieldC  docname 
---------   ------  ------  ------  --------    
1           33      44      22      firstdoc.doc,seconddoc.doc,thirddoc.doc 
2           15      23      73      
3           26      73      34      lastdoc.doc,onedoc.doc
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I tried it straight as yours in SQL Management studio and the result was perfect. Now i have to transpose it with my table structure. Hopefully it will work just fine. Will post back the result :)

Comment: @Mario I edited the answer, the `replace`I was using is not necessary so i removed it. The query is somewhat more simple now

Comment: GuidoG, absolutely fantastic :)  Flagged as the answer, thank you a bunch :)